# Angular 2+ - creating separate packages for core and shared and managing these in GIT

Tags: angular, git, single-page-application, branching-and-merging

I am a bit new to GIT so not sure if this is possible / sensible.

However I have an SPA app that has some folders that could be shared across multiple applications (core and shared in image below)

What I would like to is

1. Make these into reusable packages that can be shared across multiple applications
2. Give them a separate branch in GIT so when changes are made to them by a developer on any application that uses them can be managed separately from the application itself.
3. Allow one team to choose what version of the packages they use in their project.

My main question is around breaking out the existing packages so they can be shared across two apps.

[image]

Comment: [Something like this ?](https://medium.com/@tomsu/how-to-build-a-library-for-angular-apps-4f9b38b0ed11)

Comment: A look at these might help too - https://gomonorepo.org/ and http://www.gigamonkeys.com/mono-vs-multi/

Comment: Consider making a npm package, mainted from a different repo